# after app exit, reboot device on android

Tags: android

I want after app exit, reboot my device on android

I try app exit this.

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
finish();
android.os.Process.KillProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

it is app exit normal work.

and I try reboot this.

```
static Process rebootProcess;
try {
     rebootProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "poweroff"});
} catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Each of the well operation

but add reboot code , app exit code .

only app exit code operation

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
finish();
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    try {
       rebootProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "poweroff"});
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I try run this code.

only work app exit.

in other words. after app exit. not reboot.

How I programmatically on android ?

thanks.

please advice for me

Answer (score 0):

you can try use PowerManager to reboot android device like this.

```
android.os.PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
powerManager.reboot("");
```

and require in androidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT"/>
```

Comment: sorry , this not answer.   my app is not system app. so, not use `android.permission.REBOOT`.   so I use `rebootProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"su", "-c", "reboot"}); this won..   I want reboot and app exit execute.